# Intellij history (Access is denied)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

SBT project can not update. Can not understand why artifacts read only. 
PC: `Windows 10 Pro`

```
Intellij IDEA Ultimate
```

Using `Jetbrtains Toolbox`

> [error] java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\r\YandexDisk\research\drwu\SBTSpark\target.history (Access
>   is denied)

Comment: Move the project outside of the Yandex.Disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder) solve the problem. Move the project outside of the Yandex.Disk.